# Is there any way to get the coordinates from a region (city) on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

When you type in a city name, the region appears as a pink area. Is there any way to get the coordinates that make up this region? Here is an image of what I mean (Cambridge as an example):

[image]

Comment: Enhancement request for this feature in the Google Maps Javascript API [Issue 109](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109)

Comment: Well is it somewhere in the source code I can parse? Or is it invisible?

Answer (score 0):

As you see this is area. You can not describe this area with two coordinates which latitude and longitude.

Maybe this could help you:

http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

Comment: I am trying to get all of the coordinates in the region. Not just one coordinate. Multiple coordinates make up the region's polygon.